# Processing Drawing Problems

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I'm kind of new to processing so bear with me. I'm creating a basic drawing program where you click on a colored box to get that color and then you can draw and stuff. Well I already created a red box color and an eraser so I decided to create a blue box but when I click it, it doesn't change the color to blue. I have tried troubleshooting this with no luck.

Here's the code (note this works best with Eclipse and importing the processing core https://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/):

```
// note: many imports aren't used yet
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PShape;

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends PApplet{

PShape rectangle;

int color;
int color2;
int color3;
boolean red = false;
boolean blue = false;
boolean green = false;
boolean eraser = false;

// needed to create this in order for Eclipse to work
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PApplet.main("Main");
}

public void settings(){
    size(1280, 720);
}

public void setup() {
    size(1280, 720);
    smooth();
    background(255, 255, 255);
    noStroke();

}

public void draw() {
    // nothing here yet
    if (keyPressed) {

    }
    else {
        color = 0;
    }
    fill(0);

    fill(255, 0, 0);
    // red square
    rect(0, 50, 50, 50);
    fill(0, 10, 255);
    // blue square
    rect(0, 100, 50, 50);
    fill(0);


}

public void mousePressed() {
    if(red) {
        color = 255;
        color2 = 0;
        color3 = 0;
    }
    if(eraser) {
        color = 255;
        color2 = 255;
        color3 = 255;
    }
    if(blue) {
        color = 0;
        color = 10;
        color = 255;
    }
    else{
        fill(0);
    }
    // check if mouse is in drawing area
    if (mouseX >= 50 && mouseX <= 1280 && mouseY >= 0 && mouseY <= 720) {
        // change the drawing color 
        fill(color, color2, color3);
        rect(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50);
    }
    // if red
    if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseX <= 50 && mouseY >= 50 && mouseY <= 100) {
        eraser = false;
        blue = false;
        red = true;
    }
    // if eraser (note: in top left corner)
    if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseX <= 50 && mouseY >= 0 && mouseY <= 50) {
        red = false;
        blue = false;
        eraser = true;
    }
    // if blue
    if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseX <=50 && mouseY >= 100 && mouseY <= 150) {
        eraser = false;
        red = false;
        blue = true;
    }
}

// basically the same code for mousePressed
public void mouseDragged() {
    if(red) {
        color = 255;
        color2 = 0;
        color3 = 0;
    }
    if(eraser) {
        color = 255;
        color2 = 255;
        color3 = 255;
    }
    if(blue) {
        color = 0;
        color = 10;
        color = 255;
    }
    if (mouseX >= 50 && mouseX <= 1280 && mouseY >= 0 && mouseY <= 720) {
        fill(color, color2, color3);
        rect(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50);
    }
    if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseX <= 50 && mouseY >= 50 && mouseY <= 100) {
        eraser = false;
        blue = false;
        red = true;
    }
    if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseX <= 50 && mouseY >= 0 && mouseY <= 50) {
        red = false;
        blue = false;
        eraser = true;
    }
    if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseX <=50 && mouseY >= 100 && mouseY <= 150) {
        eraser = false;
        red = false;
        blue = true;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't use a variable named `color`. That might not cause an error if you're using eclipse, but it's going to be confusing because it clashes with Processing's special `color` data type.

Secondly, look at this `if` statement:

```
if(blue) {
    color = 0;
    color = 10;
    color = 255;
}
```

You're just setting `color` over and over again. Maybe you meant to use `color2` and `color3`?

That `if` statement is in two different places. If I change that to `color1`, `color2`, and `color3`, your code works okay.