# Problems with drawing program in processing

Tags: eclipse, processing

I'm creating a basic drawing program in Java processing, I have two colors down (as well as an eraser) and I just created a new color (green). For some reason when I click on green, it doesn't change the color. Thanks!

(Note, I ran this program in Eclipse with processing imported, if you are going to use just processing, change the int color to color1. Get rid of the main function, the one with PApplet.main("main");, and you should be good) if you wan't to run this in eclipse (as I did) there is an article on it here: https://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/

```java
// note: many imports aren't used yet
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PShape;

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends PApplet{

PShape rectangle;

String file = "";

char letter;

int color;
int color2;
int color3;
boolean red = false;
boolean blue = false;
boolean green = false;
boolean yellow = false;
boolean eraser = false;

boolean saving = false;

// needed to create this in order for Eclipse to work
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PApplet.main("Main");
}

public void settings(){
    size(1280, 720);
}

public void setup() {
    size(1280, 720);
    smooth();
    background(255, 255, 255);
    noStroke();

}

public void draw() {

    if (keyPressed) {

        if (key == 'c') {
            background(255, 255, 255);
        }

        if (key == 's') {
            save("Drawing.tif");

        }

    }
    else {
        color = 0;
    }
    fill(0);
    text("Press 'c' to clear the screen", 50, 700, 200, 50);
    text("Press 's' to save", 250, 700, 200, 50);

    fill(255, 0, 0);
    // red square
    rect(0, 50, 50, 50);
    fill(0, 10, 255);
    // blue square
    rect(0, 100, 50, 50);
    fill(0, 255, 40);
    // green square
    rect(0, 150, 50, 50);
    fill(255, 255, 0);
    // yellow square
    rect(0, 200, 50, 50);
    fill(0);


}

public void mousePressed() {
    if(red) {
        color = 255;
        color2 = 0;
        color3 = 0;
    }
    if(eraser) {
        color = 255;
        color2 = 255;
        color3 = 255;
    }
    if(blue) {
        color = 0;
        color2 = 10;
        color3 = 255;
    }
    if(green){
        color = 0;
        color2 = 255;
        color3 = 40;
    }
    else{
        fill(0);
    }
    // check if mouse is in drawing area
    if (mouseX >= 50 && mouseX <= 1280 && mouseY >= 0 && mouseY <= 680) {
        // change the drawing color 
        fill(color, color2, color3);
        rect(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50);
    }
    // if red
    if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseX <= 50 && mouseY >= 50 && mouseY <= 100) {
        eraser = false;
        blue = false;
        green = false;
        red = true;
    }
    // if eraser (note: in top left corner)
    if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseX <= 50 && mouseY >= 0 && mouseY <= 50) {
        red = false;
        blue = false;
        green = false;
        eraser = true;
    }
    // if blue
    if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseX <=50 && mouseY >= 100 && mouseY <= 150) {
        eraser = false;
        red = false;
        green = false;
        blue = true;
    }
    // if green
    if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseY <= 50 && mouseY >= 150 && mouseY <= 200) {
        eraser = false;
        red = false;
        blue = false;
        green = true;
    }
}

// basically the same code for mousePressed
public void mouseDragged() {
    if(red) {
        color = 255;
        color2 = 0;
        color3 = 0;
    }
    if(eraser) {
        color = 255;
        color2 = 255;
        color3 = 255;
    }
    if(blue) {
        color = 0;
        color2 = 10;
        color3 = 255;
    }
    if(green){
        color = 0;
        color2 = 255;
        color3 = 40;
    }
    else{
        fill(0);
    }
    // check if mouse is in drawing area
    if (mouseX >= 50 && mouseX <= 1280 && mouseY >= 0 && mouseY <= 680) {
        // change the drawing color 
        fill(color, color2, color3);
        rect(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50);
    }
    // if red
    if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseX <= 50 && mouseY >= 50 && mouseY <= 100) {
        eraser = false;
        blue = false;
        green = false;
        red = true;
    }
    // if eraser (note: in top left corner)
    if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseX <= 50 && mouseY >= 0 && mouseY <= 50) {
        red = false;
        blue = false;
        green = false;
        eraser = true;
    }
    // if blue
    if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseX <=50 && mouseY >= 100 && mouseY <= 150) {
        eraser = false;
        red = false;
        green = false;
        blue = true;
    }
    // if green
    if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseY <= 50 && mouseY >= 150 && mouseY <= 200) {
        eraser = false;
        red = false;
        blue = false;
        green = true;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Java tag removed: this is a Processing question, not a Java question. Yes the languages are related, but they're not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548126/processing-drawing-problems), you really shouldn't use a variable named `color`. It might work for you in eclipse, but it's confusing. At the very least it makes it harder for us to help you. While you're at it, you should take care of things like unused import statements. See also: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

To figure out problems like this, you have to do some debugging. The first thing I'd check is: does the code ever enter your green `if` statement inside the `mousePressed()` function? So I'd add a `println()` statement inside that `if` statement, like this:

```java
  if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseY <= 50 && mouseY >= 150 && mouseY <= 200) {
    println("here");
    eraser = false;
    red = false;
    blue = false;
    green = true;
  }
```

Running the program and clicking the green square, we see that this `if` statement is never entered. That's definitely suspicious, so let's take a closer look at the `if` statement itself:

```
  if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseY <= 50 && mouseY >= 150 && mouseY <= 200) {
```

Notice anything? Read it out loud if you don't.

That second check is comparing `mouseY`. Looks like you meant to use `mouseX`.